# Https request from AWS Lambda python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-requests

I'm trying to do a simple https GET request from a python script in AWS Lambda to my webserver on EC2. But I get an **Unauthorize** code 401

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://example.com/test/validate')
```

Here is what I can see in the IIS webserver log:

```
021-11-01 22:24:42 172.1.2.3 GET /test/validate - 443 - 52.1.2.3 python-requests/2.26.0 - 401 0 0 3
```

When I execute this request in a browser, everything is fine. Am I missing something about Lambda and Https requests?

Comment: It seems to be a restriction from your server. Does your server have a firewall ? Did you try to query from other IP addresses ?

Comment: are you able to reach the web server running on EC2 from a browser, without using a vpn for example?

Comment: AFAIK a browser request also includes additional cookies and headers, like UserAgent, so that might be why a requests call wouldn't work. Can you confirm if the same `requests` call succeeds from your local machine?

Comment: It looks like it needs credentials.  Is there a login to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at the application level. It was requesting the presence of a specific cookie, otherwise it responds with a 401 http code.